# OpenGL и как его установить

Tags: c, opengl

Хочу для практики написать небольшой проект "Змейка" на СИ при помощи OpenGL. Вопрос: как и где его можно установить? Сначала по туториалам я скачал glfw. Потом заметил, что некоторые коды с разных ресурсов используют разные инклюды. Так, пример треугольника на OpenGL использует glut. Его я тоже скачал. Всё равно не работало. Увидел ещё один include <glad.h>. Я в замешательстве. Устанавливать всё по отдельности и настраивать для каждого отдельного проекта или есть один централизованный способ скачать OpenGL и не мучаться?

Comment: glfw, glut и glad — это не OpenGL

Comment: А что это тогда и для чего? Просто в некоторых обучающих OpenGL видео используются эти библиотеки.

Comment: Это вы еще не дошли до версионирования OpenGL, OpenGLES, EGL и каталога расширений для них... *"один централизованный способ скачать OpenGL и не мучаться?"* - используйте DirectX

Comment: @user7860670 бросьте каку, не надо людей на проприетарщину подсаживать

Comment: Обычно стоит учить OpenGL по https://learnopengl.com/, там и ссылка на репо со всеми примерами есть.

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте использовать SDK

Чтото базовое вроде https://github.com/okk3/OpenGL-ES-SDK

Или MESA - большой комбайн родом из линуксов https://github.com/pal1000/mesa-dist-win

Comment: А теперь еще объясните человеку, зачем ему OpenGLES с EGL, и чем оно отличается от обычного OpenGL.

Comment: Их нельзя использовать для изучения современного опенгл? Я бы взял mesa. Там есть всё

Comment: OpenGLES как бы весьма далек от OpenGL. Ну а брать mesa - это явно не подходит под "не мучиться".

Comment: На линуксе вообще из коробки.)